# Python websockets: EOFError("line without CRLF")

Tags: python, websocket

I've implemented a Python Websockets server program example.

When I connect to it via wss://myserver.com:9000, it doesn't work and I see the error
`EOFError("line without CRLF")` in my log.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an SSL (TLS) issue.

First, try connecting to your server without TLS: use protocol `ws` instead of `wss`. If that works, your problem is lack of TLS (SSL) support. To fix:

1. Ensure that your Python installation has SSL support.
2. Make or get an X.509 server certificate. Depending your WebSocket **client**, you may be able to use a self-signed certificate. But you'll often need a real cert and they are free from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).
3. `pip ssl` to get the SSL library
4. Add SSL to your startup:

```
import ssl
...
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain("path/to/fullchain.pem", "path/to/privkey.pem")
...
    server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect, "", 9000, subprotocols=["ocpp1.6"], ssl=ssl_context
    )
```